# Как сделать слайды разного размера на slick?

Tags: html, css, jquery, slick.js

[image: слайдер]
Кто нибудь сталкивался с подобной задачей, помогите решить задачу

Comment: вы про ширину? там вроде настройки есть такие

Comment: я имею в виду, как мне сделать разный размер у слайдов, чтобы это работало по типу - нажимаю на стрелку и 2 слайд сменяет первый(применяя на себя эффект активного элемента, как на первом слайде), а третий сменяет второй и т.д

Comment: а за что минусы-то? сразу 2 прилетело в ответ, чтоб я знала уж.

Comment: Я не ставил, сидел разбирался в твоем коде, а ты удалила

Comment: на jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Reikiki/f1h98ark/

Answer (score 0):

```
variableWidth: true,
```

применяется в слайдере, где ширина у картинок разная.
после этого размер не устанавливается автоматом

Answer (score 0):

Используйте такой принцип. Я не стал грузить slick-slider сюда, просто взял структуру его начиная с ".slick-track"
Также к ".slick-slide" добавил "transition", но вы там его уже сами настройте, я ж не знаю с какой скоростью идёт прокрутка.

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.slick-track {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 15px;
}
.slick-slide {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.slick-slide.slick-current {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.slick-slide.slick-current + .slick-slide {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
.slick-slide.slick-current + .slick-slide + .slick-slide {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slick-track">
  <div class="slick-slide slick-current">
    
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slide slick-current">
    
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slide slick-current">
    
  </div>
</div>
```